# Using identical Keras ImageDataGenerator and Albumentations augmentations result in different training perfomances

Tags: python, keras, albumentations

I use image augmentation for an image segmentation task, training a Unet. Since the Keras ImageDataGenerator doesn't have a lot of options for augmenting I tried out Albumentations (Library specifically designed for augmentations). First I wanted to replicate the Keras augmentations and see if the Albumentations augmentations would perform the same (...which they do not). The new library actually performs worse on the validation data and the model is slightly overfitting.

The code below shows the two different generators (Keras vs Albumentations). It's the only part of the code that I changed so the issue should be found here. One thing that I found is that Keras uses spline interpolation (1st order) and Albumentations uses normal linear interpolation. A spline interpolation (1st order) is just a domain of linear interpolations, so I believe it's the same (not sure though).

So my question is: **Why do they not perform the exact same even though the augmentation techniques and the parameters are exactly the same?** I know that there is some randomness involved but I tested this with several trainings and always had similar results.

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import albumentations as A

# parameters
rotation_range=10.0
width_shift_range=0.1
height_shift_range=0.1
shear_range=0.5
zoom_range=0.1
horizontal_flip=True
c_fill_val = -2
label_chans = 2

def keras_build_generator(img, lab):
    img, lab = (np.expand_dims(data, axis=0) for data in [img, lab])
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=rotation_range,
        width_shift_range=width_shift_range, 
        height_shift_range=height_shift_range,
        shear_range=shear_range,
        zoom_range=zoom_range,
        horizontal_flip=horizontal_flip,
        fill_mode="constant", 
        cval=c_fill_val
    )
    image_generator = datagen.flow(img, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
    label_generator = datagen.flow(lab, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
    return zip(image_generator, label_generator)


def alb_build_transformer():
    random.seed(10)
    transformer = A.Compose([
        A.Affine(   
            interpolation=1,
            mask_interpolation=1,
            always_apply=True,
            rotate=(-rotation_range, rotation_range),
            translate_percent={
                'x':(-width_shift_range, width_shift_range),
                'y':(-height_shift_range, height_shift_range)
            },
            shear=[-shear_range, shear_range],
            scale={
                'x':(1-zoom_range, 1+zoom_range),
                'y':(1-zoom_range, 1+zoom_range)
            },
            cval=c_fill_val,
            cval_mask=c_fill_val,
            mode=0,
            fit_output=False,
        ),
        A.HorizontalFlip(
            p=0.5 if horizontal_flip else 0
        ),
    ])
    return transformer
```

EDIT:
Changed the Albumentations library source code so it's using a spline interpolation (just like Keras). Results show that Albumentations is performing even worse.. So this is probably not the issue.

Comment: Did you get to find out what had happened?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not..